# change request filename (%{REQUEST_FILENAME}) to new path in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use `RewriteRule` in **.htaccess** same as `Alias /var/www/html/core/ Alias /var/www/html/core/latest/`.

I made this **.htaccess** in **/var/www/html/core**:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Check if file exist in original path (/var/www/html/core):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

#try new path (/var/www/html/core/latest):
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ latest/$1 [NC,L]
```

It's works. but if file has not been exist in **/var/www/html/core/latest** apache show Internal Server Error instead of a normal 404 error. So I have to use some `RewriteCond *** -f` before last `RewriteRule` in order to ensure file exist in new path.

Problem is I can't change `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` to `latest/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`. for example:

**core/img/loading.gif** must checked in **core/latest/img/loading.gif** , not **latest/core/img/loading.gif**

Is it possible to parse `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` in .htaccess somehow?

Comment: Are you using both mod-alias and mod-rewrite?

Comment: Yes, first `AliasMatch ^/core/?(.*) /var/www/html/core/$1` in apache's config. Then **.htaccess** in core directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tweak your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /core/

#Check if file exist in original path (/var/www/html/core):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#try new path (/var/www/html/core/latest):
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/core/latest/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^((?!latest/).*)$ latest/$1 [L,NC]
```

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/core/latest/$1 -f` makes sure that file exists in `/core/latest/` folder.